# How to query number of changes in a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores items with two properties. So the table has three columns:

```
 item_id  |  property_1  |  property_2  |  insert_time
  1       |   10         |  100         |  2012-08-24 00:00:01
  1       |   11         |  100         |  2012-08-24 00:00:02
  1       |   11         |  101         |  2012-08-24 00:00:03
  2       |   20         |  200         |  2012-08-24 00:00:04
  2       |   20         |  201         |  2012-08-24 00:00:05
  2       |   20         |  200         |  2012-08-24 00:00:06
```

That is, each time *either* property of any item changes, a new row is inserted. There is also a column storing the insertion time.  Now I want to get the number of changes in `property_2`. For the table above, I should get

```
item_id  |  changes_in_property_2
 1       |    2
 2       |    3
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Do you have an id column on the table, or a datetime field for each record?  Just curious, otherwise is there a way to sequence the records?

Comment: You are going to have problems determining changes given that there is no difference between row 4 and row 6 in your example data. You will probably need to add some sort of sortable chronological information to allow fro traversal, in order, comparing previous and next values.

Comment: It will be **very** difficult to determine the change since row 4 and row 6 are identical. You need another column or different recording method.

Comment: @Tom,@ahillman3,@njk  I do have a column of insertion time.  I just edited my question.

Comment: @seanhawk what is the key on your table?

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you how many distinct values were entered. If it was changed back to a previous value, it will not be counted as a new change, though. Without a chronology to your data, hard to do much more.

```
select item_id, count(distinct property_2)
from Table1
group by item_id
```

Comment: I do have a column of insertion time. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closest that I could get to your desired result. I should note however, that you are asking for the number of changes to `property_2` based on `item_id`. If you are analyzing strictly those two columns, then there is only 1 change for `item_id` 1 and 2 changes for `item_id` 2. You would need to expand your result to aggregate by `property_1`. Hopefully, this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76853/1) will show you why.

```
SELECT a.item_id,  
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN a.property_2 <> 
        (SELECT property_2 FROM tbl b 
          WHERE b.item_id = a.item_id AND b.insert_time > a.insert_time LIMIT 1) THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END) AS changes_in_property_2
FROM tbl a
GROUP BY a.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

My take :

```
SELECT 
    i.item_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.property_1 != p.property_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 1
      AS changes_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.property_2 != p.property_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 1
      AS changes_2
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN items p
  ON p.time = 
    (SELECT MAX(q.insert_time) FROM items q 
        WHERE q.insert_time < i.insert_time AND i.item_id = q.item_id)
GROUP BY i.item_id;
```

There is one entry for each item that is not selected in `i`, the one that has no predecessor. It counts for a change though, that's why the sums are incremented.

Comment: @Anime what is `p.time` referring to? What if there are no changes for an `item_id`? It seems that you will add 1 even if there is no change.

Comment: I know, it's confusing, but if you look closely at the number the OP gives, every first entry for an item is itself considered a change. As you can see he wants 2 changes for (`item_1`, `property_2`) even though there is only one leap from `100` to `101`.
For each entry in `i`, `p.time` refers to the insert_time of the previous entry for the same item. Thus, since we're using an inner join, entries with no predecessors will not appear, so we have to add them manually to the sum (and we know there is always exactly 1 for each item).

Comment: I've just noticed it's better to do a `LEFT JOIN` in case an item has only one entry. It doesn't mess up the sums since entries with no predecessor will have `p.property_1` and `p.property_2` to `NULL`, which causes the `CASE ... WHEN` construct to return 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, with user-defined variables to keep track of the previous row's value.

```
SELECT item_id, MAX(c) AS changes_in_property_2
FROM (
    SELECT IF(@i = item_id, IF(@p = property_2, @c, @c:=@c+1), @c:=1) AS c, 
        (@i:=item_id) AS item_id,
        (@p:=property_2) 
    FROM `no_one_names_their_table_in_sql_questions` AS t,
    (SELECT @i:=0, @p:=0) AS _init
    ORDER BY insert_time
) AS sub
GROUP BY item_id;
```