# MySQL Winning Streak for every Player

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with winner and loser statistics from a game:

```
id           winner_id   loser_id 

1            1          2             
2            1          2             
3            3          4             
4            4          3             
5            1          2             
6            2          1             
7            3          4             
8            3          2   
9            3          5             
10           3          6             
11           2          3   
12           3          6             
13           2          3
```

I want a result table where i can find the highest winning streak of every player in the game. A streak of a player is broken, when he lost a game (player_id = loser_id). It should look like:

```
player_id    win_streak

1            3                     
2            2                     
3            4                       
4            1                      
5            0                      
6            0
```

I tried many queries with user defined variables etc. but i can't find a solution. Thanks!

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3da5f/1

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was wondering why it appeared in my question ;)

Comment: What does your table should reflect ? The best winning streak or the latest?

Comment: Sounds like a Gap and Islands problem, see my old question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414603/sql-change-number-column

Comment: @DiegoTercero Danny would need to confirm but my understanding is that he wants the latest winning streaks for each of the users.

Comment: I would like to have the overall winning streak for each player

Comment: Then your desired result is wrong for your example... you should add the rest of the streaks for each players...

Comment: Why do you really want to do this with stats computation ? Can't you just keep an internal variable that keeps track of current player's winning streak and update some "win_streak" counter on its profile table only when it's greater than what's already stored in the DB ?

Comment: @Jorge Campos, you are right! My goal is the highest streak of each player. I edited the question.

Comment: @DiegoTercero Your suggested approach is also possible for me but i still need a correct query

Comment: why `playerid=1` and `win_streak=3` ?? he has 3 wins and 1 losses, so imho it should be **3-1=2** isn't it?

Comment: 'playerid=1' won 3 games before he lost 1 => **Streak = 3**

Comment: @Alex it is right alex. 1 - won, 1 - won 1- won then a 1- lost if 1 had won another it should be 2 streaks for player 1 3-1 and 1-1

Comment: Well, either you're going to have to use that variable i talked about inside a mysql cursor, or in your app code.

You have to do sequential agregation (count) conditional to an event that might or not happen later during your scan (a result record that might appear later might end a streak or increase the counter). Your SQL code is really going to be ugly.

Better to keep your data model clean and do that counting on your app code.

Comment: I think this is a query for the gurus like @GordonLinoff

Comment: it is not so dufficult to get this query, it is just not very efficient the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should better to do that on php (or any other language you use) side.

But just to give you some idea and as experiment and example for some unique cases (hope it could be useful somewhere)

Here is my approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57cc65/1

```
SELECT r.winner_id,
  (SELECT MAX(IF(winner_id=r.winner_id,IF(@i IS NULL, @i:=1,@i:=@i+1), IF(loser_id = r.winner_id, @i:=0,0)))
   FROM Results r1
   WHERE r1.winner_id = r.winner_id
     OR r1.loser_id = r.winner_id
  GROUP BY IF(winner_id=r.winner_id, winner_id,loser_id)) win_streak

FROM ( SELECT winner_id
      FROM Results
      GROUP BY winner_id
      ) r
```

It returns not all ids now but only who had ever win. So to make it better, probably you have `user` table. If so it would simplify a query. If you have no `user` table you need to `union all` somehow users who had never win.

You are welcome if any questions.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the fast response! Yes, i have this **user table** you mentioned in your answer. My additional goal is the update of this **user table** with the streaks for every player. I tried your query on my **result table** but the resulting win_streak for every player is 1. I don't understand this behaviour but i am trying to fix it for my database. At the moment i have ~2000 unique players and ~110.000 results (game stats). If i am trying to update my **user table** with your streak query it is loading forever :/

Comment: Just provide your `results` table dataset you can pick 1,2,3 players and create the fiddle. We can figure that out then. because as you can see my query works fine with the sample you've been provided. And by the way - that is what I told you from the beginning: this kind of query has not very best performance. So you can run this query in the loop with some limitation like: `WHERE winner_id>10 AND winner_id<=20`

Comment: I'm not convinced that this query works fine - but (I think) only because there's a problem with how @i is initiated.

Comment: @Strawberry neither do I :-) But I need something from author to continue development. This is very weird question from the beginning. So I just don't want to waste extra time to order and group everything if nobody need it finally.

Comment: @Alex I created a fiddle where your query is working well! [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3cb3d/1) The problem on my database (with  ~2000 unique players and ~110.000 results): Every win_streak is 1...

Comment: @Alex Although your query isn't working on my big data set, it is successful on your fiddle with small examples! Thanks for that and the hint with the usage of php. I handle the streaks now with php and it is working much faster. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

Is this the same as Alex's approach; I'm not quite sure, except that it seems to have one distinct advantage.... ;-)

```
SELECT player_id, MAX(CASE WHEN result = 'winner' THEN running ELSE 0 END) streak 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT *
            , IF(player_id = @prev_player,IF(result=@prev_result,@i:=@i+1,@i:=1),@i:=1) running
            , @prev_result := result 
            , @prev_player:=player_id
         FROM 
            ( SELECT id, 'winner' result, winner_id player_id FROM my_table
               UNION
              SELECT id, 'loser', loser_id FROM my_table
            ) x
            , 
            ( SELECT @i:=1,@prev_result = '',@prev_player:='' ) vars
        ORDER  
           BY x.player_id
            , x.id
     ) a
 GROUP 
    BY player_id;
```

Comment: players 5 and 6! nice one! but still not showing all streaks from all players as OP asked (in comments). +1 though

Comment: @JorgeCampos you've lost me

Comment: @JorgeCampos  I've checked Strawberry's query - it works fine with my fiddle. What is your point?

Comment: OP said on comments that he need ALL streaks of all players then his query gives you: 1-3; 2-2; 3-4; 4-1; 5-0; 6-0 when it should show: 1-3; 2-1; 2-2; 3-1; 3-4; 3-1; 4-1; 5-0; 6-0. Quating OP in comments: `I would like to have the overall winning streak for each player` after @LukeP asked

Comment: @JorgeCampos I interpret "My goal is the highest streak of each player" to mean the OP wants the highest streak of each player - but either way, this query is easy to adapt.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your answer! I have the same problem with your query like with the answer query from Alex. After running it on my table every result row for the column streak is filled with the value 1 for every player. Sorry for the confusing question - this is my very first question on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Can you prove that in a sqlfiddle

Comment: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3cb3d/1) shows the query working on a small sample set. If i use the same on my huge table, it wont work :/ sqlfiddle has a limitation so i cant reproduce the failure there

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Your query is also working on a small example but i decided to handle it with php now. Cheers!

Comment: i can't see any error here, so I'm really curious to know why it would fail. Maybe one of the gurus can enlighten us.